# Unbalanced clustering results when using 'mini batch kmeans'. Why?

Tags: python, pandas, scipy, cluster-analysis, k-means

I am using `Mini Batch KMeans` from `sklearn` to cluster data.
The parameters were as follows:

```
from sklearn.cluster import MiniBatchKMeans
clustering = MiniBatchKMeans(n_clusters=100, max_iter=100, random_state=0, reassignment_ratio = 0, batch_size=100000, compute_labels=False, verbose=True)
```

However, although i specified that i wanted the number of clusters to be `100`, the number of clusters that i got was only `10`. Also, These clusters were unbalanced:

```
   0      3205211
   95     107525
   94     76906
   97     45161
   96     44912
   92     11628
   93     8914
   98     6889
   91     3509
   90     101
```

What did i miss? What parameters do i need to fix in order to get the desired cluster size and count?

I found something similar on stackoverflow [KMeans clustering unbalanced data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52253787/kmeans-clustering-unbalanced-data) but i didn't know how to make use of it.

Comment: please include a complete example.

Comment: How did you get those numbers displayed?  Did you print them?  That looks like 100; it starts at 0 and goes to 99.  Also, you can make MiniBatchKMeans deterministic by setting random_state=0.  Finally, check out the link below.
https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.MiniBatchKMeans.html